# UICollection View Redrawing onto Itself

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uicollectionview

I am new to UICollectionViews and I was wondering how I could make it so that the following code does not redraw itself when scrolling the UICollectionView?

It works great when you initially scroll but when you then re-scroll it draws over itself again and you get duplicates on top of each other.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UICollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

UIView *tmpView;

if([self.selectedEffects isEqualToString:@"Effects"]){

    int index = indexPath.row;

    NSLog(@"%i",index);

    tmpView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 90)];
    [tmpView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    UIImageView *imageViewWithEffect = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 0, 60, 60)];
    imageViewWithEffect.layer.cornerRadius = 10.00;
    imageViewWithEffect.clipsToBounds = YES;

    UILabel *labelEffect = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 65, 70, 20)];
    [labelEffect setText:[[self.activeEffectsArray objectAtIndex:index] objectAtIndex:1]];
    labelEffect.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    labelEffect.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [labelEffect setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:8]];

    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];

    [activityIndicator setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 60)];
    activityIndicator.alpha = 1.0;
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];

    UIButton *buttonSelect = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [buttonSelect setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 90)];
    [buttonSelect setTag:index];
    [buttonSelect addTarget:self action:@selector(applyEffects:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{

        UIImage *imageWithEffect = [self editImage:[[self.activeEffectsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:0] ImageToEdit:self.thumbnailImage];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            [imageViewWithEffect setImage:imageWithEffect];
            [activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];

        });

    });

    [tmpView addSubview:imageViewWithEffect];
    [tmpView addSubview:labelEffect];
    [tmpView addSubview:activityIndicator];
    [tmpView addSubview:buttonSelect];

}

if([self.selectedEffects isEqualToString:@"Frames"]){

    int index = indexPath.row;

    tmpView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 90)];
    [tmpView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    UIImageView *imageViewWithEffect = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 0, 60, 60)];

    UILabel *labelEffect = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 65, 70, 20)];
    [labelEffect setText:[[self.activeFrameArray objectAtIndex:index] objectAtIndex:1]];
    labelEffect.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    labelEffect.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [labelEffect setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:10]];

    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];

    [activityIndicator setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 60)];
    activityIndicator.alpha = 1.0;
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];

    UIButton *buttonSelect = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [buttonSelect setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 90)];
    [buttonSelect setTag:index];
    [buttonSelect addTarget:self action:@selector(applyFrames:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{

        UIImage *imageWithEffect = [self applyFrame:[[self.activeFrameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:0] ImageToEdit:self.thumbnailImage];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            [imageViewWithEffect setImage:imageWithEffect];
            [activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];

        });

    });

    [tmpView addSubview:imageViewWithEffect];
    [tmpView addSubview:labelEffect];
    [tmpView addSubview:activityIndicator];
    [tmpView addSubview:buttonSelect];

}

[cell addSubview:tmpView];

return cell;
```

}

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem the better way to handle this would be to have a `UICollectionViewCell` subclass perhaps `ORSEffectsCell`

Inside the subclass you would configure the appropriate view hierarchies and then provide accessors to these views.

This would then mean that you are creating the cell view hierarchy once and then just reconfiguring the content for each cell.

Answer (score 0):

//Add this code in cellForItemAtIndexPath methods

```
for (UIView *v in [tmpView subviews])
        [v removeFromSuperview];
```

Tell me its working or not :)

Comment: @ORStudios thanks. when u scroll the collection view that time also init new content  so previous content stay their and over lap with new content.so u have to remove the subview before use new content in uicollectionview.

Comment: This is a pretty poor solution that is fixing the symptom not the cause.

Comment: @Paul.s yes i know but the best way to use the collectionview is to make the different cell class of uicollectionview.

Comment: Then surely that should be your answer - someone who is new will now assume that this hack is "the correct way", which it really isn't

Comment: Found another problem with the above, unfortunately each Cell should contain a image that is processed through GPUImage. I am finding that the above is causing the image to be processed each time the cell appears and it is bumping up the CPU usage on the IPhone. I need it so that the cell is loaded once only and then new cells that become visible when scrolling are also only loaded once.